# Xiaomi Mi Unlock "Not connected to the phone"

Tags: fastboot, bootloader, xiaomi

I am going insane here and I need help now.

I am trying to unlock my **Xiaomi Mi Note 4**'s bootloader since almost 2 weeks, but I am stuck in this problem where the **Mi Unlock** tool can't recognize that my phone is connected.

Yes, I already have applied for and received permission from Xiaomi to unlock my device. Yes, I have waited for more than 4 days already.
The problem here is that the Mi Unlock tool simply can't see my device in bootloader mode. And it is connected, as I can see it in the Device Manager:

[image]

Mi Unlock simply can't see it:

[image]

If I click on the gear icon on the top, it says that the drivers aren't installed:

[image]

But if I click to check, it says they are installed:

[image]

Fastboot also sees the device:

[image]

What's going on here? I really need help.
I am on **Windows 10 Professional 64-bits**, all latest updates installed.

All help appreciated.

Comment: Are you on an USB 3.0 port? Sometimes phone fails being detected on Windows 10 x64 (Can't link to the article ATM). Or You should try on Windows 7, works without a problem.

Comment: @esQmo_ I just tried all of my USB ports, but honestly, I think all of them are USB 3. I'll try a Windows 7 32-bits VM, thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, figured it out eventually.

Just extract the Mi unlock tool files into a new folder directly in the C Drive.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, this does actually work. Also try a USB 2.0 port.

Answer (score 0):

Try using 15 seconds ADB Installer but remember to turn of your windows defender or any other antivirus and you are all set for detecting and unlocking your device.

Answer (score 0):

I manually selected the WinUsb -> ADB Device as the driver, when in Fastboot mode, and now it suddenly works.